# Find an element, then insert content after the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling with this piece of code for the last few hours now.
Hopefully you can help me :)
What I try to achieve:

1. Find an element.
2. Insert html after the element that follows the elment found in (1).

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="paragraph" data-template="1" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="icons"></div>
```

I want to insert after the element with the "icons" class, so I try:

```
$(data).insertAfter('.paragraph').find('[data-id="'+appendAfter+'"]').next('.icons');
```

.. where $(data) is a HTML string

That fails.
If I remove the next() function, it inserts before icons, but that is not what I want:

```
$(data).insertAfter('.paragraph').find('[data-id="'+appendAfter+'"]');
```

So finding the element works, but not skipping the element after that and then insert.

Cheers,
Robert

Comment: What do you mean by "that fails"? Do you get a Javascript error? Does nothing happen? Do you get content inserted in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are looking for `next` , hopping the `div.paragraph` is closing like this

```
<div class="paragraph" data-template="1" data-id="1"> ..something.. </div>
<div class="icons">
```

if so correcting your code only

```
$(data).insertAfter($('.paragraph[data-id="'+appendAfter+'"]').next('.icons'));
```

or if `div.paragraph` is parent of `div.icons`, means not closing like above do it as

```
$(data).insertAfter($('.paragraph[data-id="'+appendAfter+'"]').find('.icons'));
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
I edited my original post with the correct HTML.
This was my first post here, so I was still figuring out how to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If the `.paragraph` element is the parent of `.icons` then `next()` won't work as that looks for sibling elements. You need to use `find()` to get the child element:

```
$('.paragraph[data-id="' + appendAfter + '"]').find('.icons').after(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
$(".paragraph").next().after(data)
```

You might need to consider what data is - is it html, or an element?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('.paragraph').next('.icons').after(data);
```